# Mysql Query: How many sum() recommended in single query?

Tags: mysql, sum

I have 70 different types of accounts. And I am fetching the data as per the account type.

The query like this,

```
$mainData = "SELECT 
          count(*) AS totalRows,
          sum(pay) as totalPay

          sum(case when account_type = 1 then 1 else 0 end) AS account_1_Total,
          sum(case when account_type = 1 then pay else 0 end) AS account_1_Pay,

          sum(case when account_type = 2 then 1 else 0 end) AS account_2_Total,
          sum(case when account_type = 2 then pay else 0 end) AS account_2_Pay,

          {all_account_types_here}

          FROM account_table";
```

In the end, those **sum()** are about more than 140.

So the question is, how many **sum()** is recommended in a single query?

Thanks!

**EDITED:**

The GROUP BY is the solution of it.

Comment: 'So the user can select the account and pay the amount as per the account.; - this seems to have no bearing in the question at all.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? What about using GROUP BY instead of all those SUM(CASE WHEN...) could that be an option?

Comment: I don't know of an upper limit for aggregation functions but I would look at a simpler select account_type, count(*),sum(pay) from account_table group by account_type and deal with the pivot in whatever front end tech you are sending the query output to.or not pivot it at all.

Comment: Ohh! I forget about the GROUP BY. Thanks JoakimDanielson and P.Salmon.